# CryptStringToBinary not working with a NULL terminated string. Why?

Tags: windows, cryptoapi

does anyone know why this code is not working?

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinCrypt.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
wchar_t *bin = TEXT("ProductID:1233===>55555");
BYTE out2[1000];
DWORD olen;
olen = 1000;

if (CryptStringToBinary(bin, 0, 1, out2, &olen, 0, 0) == 0)
{
    wprintf(TEXT("Failure\n"));
}
else
{
//wprintf(TEXT("rn%s\n"),out2);
    wprintf(TEXT("Success\n"));
}
system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Tom

Comment: Just to clarify, the code is working but CryptBinaryToString always returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you specified a length (parameter 2) of 0?

**Edit:** Just to clarify our eventual solution in the comments below, the code in the original question (since edited) contained two errors:

1. It was calling `CryptBinaryToString` instead of `CryptStringToBinary`.  Since it's invalid to pass a 0 in the second parameter to `CryptBinaryToString`, the function was failing.
2. It was passing 1 in the third parameter (dwFlags), which is interpreted as `CRYPT_STRING_BASE64`.  Since the string to encrypt wasn't in base 64 (it contained invalid characters such as ':'), the function was failing.  In general, passing a raw value instead of using an existing definition (e.g., `CRYPT_STRING_BASE64`) is not a good idea.

Comment: If you specify 0 in the lenght parameter the string is considered a null terminated string... so it should work. This is actually what I'm trying to get working.

Comment: Yes, but you're calling CryptBinaryToString.  :-)

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you. I updated the code with CryptStringToBinary and it's not working still. Any ideas?

Comment: This call works if I specify a normal string like 12345, but with this string that contains "=" and ">" characters doesn't work... I need this characters in the string, is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Yeah, I updated the code.. I'm indeed using CryptStringToBinary :)

Comment: It doesn't accept = and > because you passed 1 (CRYPT_STRING_BASE64) for parameter 3 and those aren't legal characters for base 64.  It seems like you want to pass CRYPT_STRING_BINARY, but you should probably review the documentation for that function and see which flag makes the most sense for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380285(VS.85).aspx

Comment: The key here is the documentation, which states that this function converts a *formatted* string; your string just happens not to match the format you specified.

Comment: Glad we figured it out... :-)